# Loading an image in custom WordPress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I created my custom plugin and want to add custom logo, but somehow it keeps redirecting me to wrong dir, this is error I get:

> GET http://localhost/logo.png 404 (Not Found)

Here is what I tried so far:

```
$plugin_dir = str_replace( $base_url, ABSPATH, $plugins_url );
$plugin_dir = plugins_url();
$plugin_dir = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ );
$plugin_dir = WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/plugins';
$plugin_dir = plugins_url( '/', __FILE__ );
```

Here is my add action:

```
    function kalbos_modifymenu() {

        add_menu_page('Kalbos', //page title
            'Kalbos', //menu title
            'manage_options', //capabilities
            'kalbos_list', //menu slug
            'kalbos_list', //function
            $plugin_dir . 'logo.png',
            '5'
            );
}
    add_action('admin_menu','kalbos_modifymenu');
```

However icon is working when i move my logo to wp-admin/logo.png dir because thats where my logo path goes even if i set it go to my plugin folder

Comment: Please check with my answer if it is working or not.

Comment: it didint work still says that my logo file dir is localhost/logo.png

Comment: What is the path of your `$plugin_dir`? And which one you are using `$plugin_dir` among those?

Comment: it should be wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/ bit my png file just goes localhost/logo.png

Comment: It should be or it is?

Comment: well it isnt for some reason

Comment: You're missing a close bracket **`}`** in `function kalbos_modifymenu()`

Comment: @brasofilo yeah i copied wrong i have the closing bracket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**`plugins_url`**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url) will (my emphasis):

> Retrieves the absolute URL to the plugins or mu-plugins directory (without the trailing slash) or, when using the `$path` argument, to a specific file under that directory. You can either specify the `$path` argument as a hardcoded path relative to the plugins or mu-plugins directory, **or conveniently pass `__FILE__` as the second argument to make the `$path` relative to the parent directory of the current PHP script file**.

So, the following will point exactly to your plugin directory **with** an ending slash:

```
$plugin_dir = plugins_url( '/', __FILE__ );
// results in http://localhost/wp-content/plugins/YOUR_PLUGIN/
```

And to target the logo, use:

```
$plugin_dir . 'logo.png'
```

Another example, to make a shortcut to your images folder:

```
$plugin_img = plugins_url( '/images/', __FILE__ );
// results in http://localhost/wp-content/plugins/YOUR_PLUGIN/images/
```

Comment: In console i get same 404 not found error. And when i inspect image the directory is : http://localhost/wp-admin/logo.png

Comment: i'm defyning `$plugin_dir` inside the function

Answer (score 0):

Try to add an other slash to `/plugins` like this: `/plugins/` and also close your quotes on the same line. At the moment you have it like `'plugins;` but the correct is `'/plugins';`

Comment: Then you must check if something is wrong with the declarations of `$plugin_dir` . But keep in mind that your syntax in `/plugins` was false.